# Making an awkward div shape

Tags: css

I was wondering if it's possible to make a complex shape with a div similar to the following:

[image]

It's basically a rounded square with the corners pinched inwards. The goal is to use a background image to fill it. I could accomplish it with a clip-mask with the following SVG pathing:

```
<path id="Path_1386" data-name="Path 1386" d="M20.148,599.906,455.922,482.262a15.989,15.989,0,0,0,11.817-15.433V139.242a15.986,15.986,0,0,0-11.632-15.381L20.335.613A15.984,15.984,0,0,0,0,15.994V584.475a15.983,15.983,0,0,0,20.148,15.431" transform="translate(0 0)" />
```

But it's a bit awkward to work with it in CSS for responsive resizing.

Comment: Great question, and I don't know if you'd be able to do this w/ an SVG. Take a look at this site, https://polypane.app/css-3d-transform-examples, 3D Transform #13 by hqdrone on CodePen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Option 1 (`transform`)

Use `transform: perspective()` with `tranfrom: rotateY()`.

```css
#box {
    background-color: #f00;
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    transform: perspective(300px) rotateY(10deg);
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

[Example on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axy2u6j1/)

##### Option 1.1

Use [`transform: matrix3d()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix3d()). You can use [generator here](http://ds-overdesign.com/transform/matrix3d.html)

```css
#box {
    background-color: #f00;
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    transform: matrix3d(0.98,0,0.17,.0005,0.00,1,0.00,0,-0.17,0,0.98,0,0,0,0,1);
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

[Example on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axy2u6j1/3/)

---

#### Option 2 (`perspective` with `transform`)

Use `perspective` with `transform: rotateY()`. This option you can use [`perspective-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective-origin) to point the position.

```css
#perspective-box {
    perspective: 400px;
    perspective-origin: left;
}

#box {
    background-color: #f00;
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateY(15deg);
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective-box">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

[Example on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axy2u6j1/1/)

##### Option 2.1

Use `perspective` with [`transform: rotate3D()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d()).

```css
#perspective-box {
    perspective: 700px;
}

#box {
    background-color: #f00;
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    transform: rotate3D(0, 1, 0, 30deg);
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="perspective-box">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

[Example on Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axy2u6j1/2/)

Answer (score 3):

`clip-path` combined with an SVG filter can do this. Adjust the stDeviation of the filter to control the radius.

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  display:grid;
  margin:20px;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

.box > div{
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 20%,100% 80%,0 100%);
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/300)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```